# Properly implement comparison of two objects with different type but semantically equivalent

Tags: c#, design-patterns, design-principles

I've found a similar question

[How to compare two distinctly different objects with similar properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725327/how-to-compare-two-distinctly-different-objects-with-similar-properties)

that may implicitly and/or in part reply to my question.

Suppose I want compare (without a lot of nested conditions) this object:

```
class ObjectA {
  public string PropertyX { get; set; }
  public char PropertyY { get; set; }
  public long PropertyZ { get; set; }
}
```

to a `System.String`. I'm interested only in **equality** or **inequality** (not a range of values about identity).

Implementing `IEquatable<string>` in  `ObjectA` is a proper choice? I don't care of what *simply works*, I want to identify the proper pattern for such case.

As other information, please consider that `ObjectA` will often be supplied as sequence of `IEnumerable<ObjectA>`.

I don't need to know if `"string"` `==` or `!=` `objectA` instance; sorting is not involved.

**Edit to clarify (and help)**

*Sorry but writing a good question is sometime difficult...*

Suppose I can't represent `ObjectA` as string for the purpose of comparison (violating encapsulation is not an option).

- In context-1 I've to match it against `PropertyY`.
- In context-2 I've to match it against an algorithm applied to `PropertyY`/`PropertyZ`.

@Oliver solution in the end of the question helps me again (and +1 again).
I can simply define a custom interface:

```
interface IContextConverter {
  string ToEquatableStringForContext1();
  string ToEquatableStringForContext2();  
}
```

Since I've also an `ObjectB` with same logic but different properties, both will implement `IContextConverter` (*or maybe I find a better name*) avoiding to violate [RAP](http://codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934).

Comment: I think that you must override Equals method, like as you see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219261/overriding-operator-how-to-compare-to-null.

Comment: What do you mean? If the `System.String` is `"Hello mum!"`, and the `ObjectA` has x, y, z equal to `"Cool"`, `'Z'`, and `42L`, how do I figure out if they are equal or not?

Comment: Don't sure I do. I think that it will be misused since it's designed to compare object of the same type... Look at the type comparison with operator (== for example). Object in the LHS and the other in the RHS are of the same type.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen, this is not important for the question. I've an algorithm of comparison and I want encapsulate it, in the more design-correct way. Possibly adhering to a pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to **not** implement `IEquatable<string>`, cause especially when working with collections, dictionaries, LINQ, etc. you don't really know when one of these methods will be called somewhere deep inside which leads maybe to subtle bugs.

Due to the fact that you like to compare two objects of different types a simple `Comparer<T>` wouldn't work also.

So either write a [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) which converts your object into the desired type (in your case a `string`) or add a method to your object like `.ToEquatableString()` and use their output to compare your object with the other string.

Here is an example on you could get all elements, that match one of a string in another collection:

```
IEnumerable<String> otherElements = new[] {"abc", "def", "ghi" };
IEnumerable<ObjectA> myObjects = GetObjects();

var matchesFound = otherElements.Join( // Take the first collection.
              myObjects, // Take the second collection.
              s => s, // Use the elements in the first collection as key (the string).
              obj => obj.ToEquatableString(),  // Create a string from each object for comparison.
              (s, obj) => obj, // From the matching pairs take simply the objects found.
              StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // Use a special string comparer if desired.
```

Comment: +1, @Oliver, ToEquatableString() returns a wrapper of ObjectA that implements IEquatable<string>?

Comment: @jay: No. It returns a string that represents `objectA`. So essentially the same like `.ToString()` does. This string can than be used like any other string for comparison.

Comment: +1, wanted to write the same. While this interface is provided by the framework, i think in 99.9999% of the cases its a very bad idea to use it. With all the examples ive seen so far using it (or similar concepts), its done nothing good, but created an unreadable and non - clear code, instead of a simple `ObjectA.PropertyX == "string"`, which can be understood by even someone who wrote his first "Hello world!" a day before.

Comment: @Oliver, it seems the more simple solution; but also TypeConverter solution seems clean. This answer my question.

Comment: @Oliver, last editing clarify and presents a clean implementation. Sorry I can't +1 again...

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities.

If you feel an `ObjectA` is a kind of `System.String`, you could write a user-defined conversion (implicit or explicit) from `ObjectA` to `System.String`, or from `System.String` to `ObjectA`, or both directions.

You could also overload the `==` and `!=` operators with a signature like `operator ==(ObjectA oa, string s)`. Beware that there is difference between `oa == s` and `s == oa`.

Either of these two possibilities may lead to confusion. It would also be confusing to override the virtual `Equals(object)`, or to introduce an overload `Equals(string)`. Therefore I don't recommend implementing `IEquatable<string>`.

Why not simply write a method with an unused name, like `public bool EqualsString(string s)`? Then you will have to call this method explicitly, of course, but that will lead to less confusion. Another idea would be to use a constructor of signature `public ObjectA(string s)` and then implement "homogeneous" equality of `ObjectA` and `ObjectA`.

Comment: +1 @Jeppe Stig Neilsen, liked the `ObjectA::EqualsString(string)` solution. It leads to code that it's simple and clear to read (and as more I learn, this is my priority).

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I do not particulary recommend this solution for this particular case, but I have often used this framework to implement Value Equality for structs. Difficult trade-offs are common in our field, and answers that address those, accompanied by appropriate caveats, seem in order.

I take it that you wish to design Value Equality semamtics on your class in the same fashion as the .NET framework does this for the string class.  At a minimum, the following is necessary:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) { 
  return (obj is ObjectA) && this == (ObjectA)obj; 
}
bool IEquatable<ObjectA>.Equals(ObjectA rhs) { 
  return this == rhs; 
}
public static bool operator != (ObjectA lhs, ObjectA rhs) { 
  return ! (lhs == rhs); 
}
public static bool operator == (ObjectA lhs, ObjectA rhs) {
  return (lhs.PropertyX == rhs.PropertyX);
}
public override int GetHashCode() { 
  return PropertyX.GetHashCode() 
}
```

Expanding to allow Value comparisons beween ObjectA and string:

```
bool IEquatable<ObjectA>.Equals(string rhs) { 
  return this == rhs; 
}
public static bool operator != (ObjectA lhs, string rhs) { 
  return ! (lhs == rhs); 
}
public static bool operator != (string lhs, ObjectA rhs) { 
  return ! (lhs == rhs); 
}
public static bool operator == (ObjectA lhs, string rhs) {
  return (lhs.PropertyX == rhs);
}
public static bool operator == (string lhs, ObjectA rhs) {
  return (lhs == rhs.PropertyX);
}
```

Comment: +1 for sample code. But still in doubt that this is the solution. My primary need is to search an IEnumerable<ObjectA> using System.String without moving comparison logic to the Linq query.

Comment: @jay: see update. You may encounter difficulties if the framework attempts to perform string.Equals(ObjectA) instead of ObjectA.Equals(string). I do not recommend this, as it is likely dependent on version specific implementation of the framework.

Comment: this explains better you solution. Appreciated.